# SwiftUI View gets offset to the right when using Geometry Reader and ScrollVIew

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using a ScrollView inside of a GeometryReader in SwiftUI, but everything inside the scroll view gets offset to the left, or at least the items inside the scroll view think that the boundary of the view extends far past the actual boundary of the view. as seen below. I am using the public release of Xcode 12 from the mac app store along with macOS Big Sur beta 8.

Here's the code to recreate this.

```
struct TextClassifierMMLView: View {
    @State var nLayers = 5
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                    GrayNumberStepperCard(text: "Layers", geo: geo, upperRange: 1000, lowerRange: 1, value: self.$nLayers).padding()
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle(Text("Text Classifier"))
    }
}


struct GrayNumberStepperCard: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var geo: GeometryProxy
    @State var upperRange: Int
    @State var lowerRange: Int
    @Binding var value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(text)
                .font(.custom("OpenSans-SemiBold", size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Stepper(value: $value, in: lowerRange...upperRange) {
                Text("\(self.value)")
            }.padding()
        }.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 15)
        .padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "F0F5F5"))
        )
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of view items going off the screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `GeometryReader` in this layout at all, it only confuses automatic layout.

Here is modified code. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image]

```
struct TextClassifierMMLView: View {
    @State var nLayers = 5
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView{
                 VStack{
                      GrayNumberStepperCard(text: "Layers", upperRange: 1000, lowerRange: 1, value: self.$nLayers).padding()
                 }
        }.navigationTitle(Text("Text Classifier"))
    }
}


struct GrayNumberStepperCard: View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var upperRange: Int
    @State var lowerRange: Int
    @Binding var value: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(text)
                .font(.custom("OpenSans-SemiBold", size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

            Spacer()

            Stepper(value: $value, in: lowerRange...upperRange) {
                Text("\(self.value)")
            }.padding()
        }.frame(height: 15)
        .padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        )
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think the offsetting is some sort of an Xcode / SwiftUI bug or is my code just bad?

Comment: This is not a good answer, because you might want to wrap a view with GeometryReader to offer a proxy for communicating dimensions about the coordinate space - such as to detect if scrolling has occured and to perform segues or animations on UI elements within the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

simple fix. set the HStack spacing to 0

```
HStack(spacing: 0){
...
```